# Function VLOOKUP from another workbook throws 'Cell currently evaluated contains a constant'

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I try to do a simple VLOOKUP from another workbook (in the same folder, open), for which the syntax is:

```
    =VLOOKUP([@MtkNr];'[file.xlsx]Gesamtliste'!$E$2:$Z$76;5;0)
```

(Ideally I would write

```
    =VLOOKUP([@MtkNr];'[file.xlsx]Gesamtliste'!Teilnehmer[MtkNr];[Note];0)
```

But as I understood table names are not allowed if it is from another workbook.)

But Excel simply shows me the formula, and if I try to evaluate it, it tells me

```
    The cell currently evaluated contains a constant
```

What can be the problem here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have both Excels open at the same time? It makes it easier, usually I just have both Excels open and write the formula and the file does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

`[Note]` is not an integer; it is the column header label for one of the columns in your table. To convert it to a number, use MATCH across the header row.

```
=VLOOKUP([@MtkNr]; '[file.xlsx]Gesamtliste'!Teilnehmer[MtkNr]; MATCH("Note", MtkNr[#Headers], 0); FALSE)
```

You  might be happier with an INDEX/MATCH function pair using structured table references.

Comment: Thanks! For simplicity I for now just hardcoded the cells, but it still doesn't evaluate :/
`=VLOOKUP([@MtkNr];'[Strategische Interaktion WS1617 Teilnehmer.xlsx]Gesamtliste'!$E$2:$Z$76;5;0)`